# View full contents of a matrix in Euler Math Toolbox

Tags: matrix, euler-math-toolbox

How to display all the numbers from a given matrix in Euler Math Toolbox? It doesn't seem to show more than 8 columns at a time, which isn't enough as I frequently need to view more than that.

Output I'm getting as of now:

[image: Output I'm getting as of now]

Comment: I don’t think the MATLAB tag is useful here, MATLAB doesn’t behave this way, and this program specifically says it’s not compatible with MATLAB. But if you remove that tag nobody will see your question. Does the Euler Math Toolbox have a user’s group / mailing list you can ask thus question on?

Comment: @CrisLuengo The [sourceforge discussion section of this project](https://sourceforge.net/p/eumat/discussion/general/thread/2b9b83d4/) appears to be "_the official support and discussion forum for Euler Math Toolbox_", although it seems quite abandoned. My best bet would be to email the creator directly. Jim - what do you mean by "need to use"? Is this like a homework assignment? Seeing how difficult it is to get support for this tool, I would strongly suggest trying something more mainstream like Octave or Python.

Comment: Yes this is a tool my university uses for working with matrices so I even though I know this would be easier in other programs, I have to stick with this. In class we were told to do it by requesting the matrix line by line but that seems unreliable and prone to error when copying or requesting data. The official page offers tutorials but there is no example where a dataset was large enough to present this problem.

Comment: How about exporting as CSV or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://euler.rene-grothmann.de/reference/eulercore.html#largematrices) says:

> Large matrices or vectors might not print in full size. To change this, toggle the behavior with:
>
> ```
> largematrices on
> largematrices off
> ```
>
> or use the operator `showlarge`.
>
> ```
> showlarge random(10,10)
> ```
>
> See:
>     [showlarge (Basic Utilities)](http://euler.rene-grothmann.de/reference/util.html#showlarge)

The [link](http://euler.rene-grothmann.de/reference/util.html#showlarge) in the above documentation link directs here:

> `function prefix showlarge (x$)`
>     Prints large matrices in full.
>
> By default EMT eclipses lines and rows of large matrices. This can be used to see the full matrix. If the parameter is a variable the variable name will be printed.
>
> The default can be changed with *largematrices on*/*off*.
>
> ```
> x=random(20,5); showlarge(x)
> showlarge(random(20,5))
> ```
>
> See:
>     [largematrices (Euler Core)](http://euler.rene-grothmann.de/reference/eulercore.html#largematrices),
>     [show (Maxima Documentation)](http://euler.rene-grothmann.de/reference/maximacore.html#show)